# TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined - even that i pass some data in props to that component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I don't understand one thing, why is that giving me an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined"?

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as ROUTES from '../../../constants/routes';

function Summary({ reservationData }) {
    if (reservationData.participants !== "" && reservationData.city !== "" && reservationData.day !== "" && reservationData.hour !== "") {
        return (
            <div>Summary<br />
                Participants: {reservationData.participants} <br />
                City: {reservationData.city} <br />
                Day: {reservationData.day} <br />
                Hour: {reservationData.hour} <br />
                {console.log(reservationData)}
            </div>

        );
    } else {
        { this.props.history.push(ROUTES.RESERVATION) }
    }
}
```

It is giving me an error on that last line in else statement

```
} else {
    { this.props.history.push(ROUTES.RESERVATION) }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Summary` is a functional component and doesn't have access to `this`. In order to use `props.history` in a function component you can destructure the arguments like below.

```
function Summary({ reservationData, history }) {
    if (reservationData.participants !== "" && reservationData.city !== "" && reservationData.day !== "" && reservationData.hour !== "") {
        return (
            <div>Summary<br />
                Participants: {reservationData.participants} <br />
                City: {reservationData.city} <br />
                Day: {reservationData.day} <br />
                Hour: {reservationData.hour} <br />
                {console.log(reservationData)}
            </div>

        );
    } else {
        history.push(ROUTES.RESERVATION;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the thing, sorry for a stupid question, but thanks for answering

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Can see that you are doing in a Class Component way.

If you used to use props in your component you can do

```
function Summary(props) {
    // Then access the history and reservationData in this way
    const { reservationData, history } = props

    history.push(ROUTES.RESERVATION);

    // Or
    props.history.push(ROUTES.RESERVATION)

}
```

If you think the code is a little bit troublesome, You can follow what Shubham Khatri did

```
function Summary({ reservationData, history}) {
    history.push(ROUTES.RESERVATION)
}
```

**this.props** is only able to use in class Component.

All of these is valid, writing style is up to you, feel free to try different approach, Happy Learning.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `this`. you have to create component in class react style.

```
class Summary extends React.Component {
  render() {
    //...
    this.props.history.push(ROUTES.RESERVATION)
  }
}

export default withRouter(Summary)
```